# Override orderby to create list of users by custom meta_value

Tags: loop, users, meta-value

I'm having issues ordering a loop of users by a custom meta_value. Reading the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) for `get_users()`, it doesn't actually say that you can use the `meta_value` for orderby. When I try to do it I get a list of users not ordered by the meta_value.

```
<ul>
<?php
$args = array(
'role' => 'author' ,
'meta_key' => 'score',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',//Tried meta_value also
'order' => 'DESC',
'number' => 5,
);
$blogusers = get_users($args);
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
    echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'score',true);
}
?>
</ul>
```

So what I need to do is override the orderby function by hooking into the pre_user_query. I found [this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20606) snippet but was told not to use create_function. So what is the right way to do this to order a list of users by  user meta_value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, but replace `METAKEY` to the key-name of your metadata.

```
<?php 
function cmp( $a, $b )
{ 
  if(  $a->METAKEY ==  $b->METAKEY ){ return 0 ; } 
  return ($a->METAKEY < $b->METAKEY ) ? -1 : 1;
} 

?>

<ul>
<?php
$args = array(
'role' => 'author' ,
'meta_key' => 'METAKEY',
'number' => 5,
);
$blogusers = get_users($args);
usort($blogusers ,'cmp');

foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';
    echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'METAKEY', true);
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This created the same ordered list of users. What is the purpose of that function exactly and how do I order the list?

Comment: The magic is in function `cmp`. By changing `return (... > ...) ...` to `return (... < ...) ...` you will change the order.

Comment: I had just finally found this method here too http://clarklab.com/posts/sort-wordpress-users-by-custom-meta-value-with-get_users/ ...Got it working great TY!